# How to know the time interval between two dates in swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, augmented-reality

So I'm working on an AR app. Every 3 seconds a new node appears around the room the player's in until there are 25 created. In the creation time of them the user have to destroy the nodes as soon as they're created. But I want to create a time interval between the first node the user destroyed and the last one, so I can show the time taken to do so to the user, track the high score and all that.

```
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        guard let touch = touches.first else {return}
    
        let location = touch.location(in: self)
        let node = nodes(at: location)
        
        if let sprite = node.first {
        let scaleOut = SKAction.scale(to: 3, duration: 0.4)
        let fadeOut = SKAction.fadeOut(withDuration: 0.4)
            let remove = SKAction.removeFromParent()
        let group = SKAction.group([scaleOut, fadeOut])
        let sequence = SKAction.sequence([group, remove])
            sprite.run(sequence)
            targetCount -= 1
        
    }
```

The guard statement makes sure that the computer can capture the first touch the user did, and then that touch save it in a variable, consults the location of that touch in the view. Then if there's any node at that location, the first one it'll be removed with animations using SKActions. If I need to be more specific, tell me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: So basically you have a timestamp property that you set when the first node is touched and then you have a timestamp or interval property you set/calculate when the last node is touched. You need to identify where in the code to do this, I guess `touchesBegan` can be used for both operations.

Answer (score 3):

I think what you want to do is something like:

```swift
let startTime = Date()

/* Then some time later */

let timeInterval = Date().timeIntervalSince(startTime)
```

`timeInterval` is a `TimeInterval`, which is a type alias for `Double`.  It's the number of seconds between the two `Date` instances.

On the other hand, if what you want to do is actually delay to do something, but don't actually need the timeInterval for anything other reason, look into `DispatchSemphore.wait(timeout:)` or `DispatchQueue.asyncAfter(...)`

Comment: I was thinking about that, but I don’t know where to put it. I have two variables, one is counting the nodes created and the other is counting the nodes destroyed by the user. So I was thinking about adding an if statement, something like “if targetsCreated == 25, and then I put the startTime, but the var could only be used within that statement.

Comment: Can it be a property of the object where you override `touchesBegan(_: with:)`?

Comment: Could you be more explicit? I don’t know exactly what u mean

Comment: You said that your var could only be be used within the if statement you were contemplating.   If the var were moved outside of the function and made a property of the function into whatever UIResponder - probably your view - then it would persist between events and be available for the next one.